# Where to declare config in Meteor server side code

Tags: javascript, meteor

I would like to know what is the best practice to declare configuration for packages on server side, I see two options but I don't know which of these one I should rely on.

Directly in the script :

```
CustomPackage.config({});
```

In a Meteor.startup() method :

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    CustomPackage.config({});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways are correct.
It all depends if your config needs to be set after the application has fully started or not.

I would wrap things that depend of existing data like :

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Rooms.find().count() === 0) {
      Rooms.insert({name: "Initial room"});
    }
  });
}
```

in your cause you don't have to wrap the config

from meteor docs:

It's good practice to wrap all code that isn't inside template events, template helpers, Meteor.methods, Meteor.publish, or Meteor.subscribe in Meteor.startup so that your application code isn't executed before the environment is ready.

http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-isServer

Comment: I put my server side configs in server/config.js or at the top of the js file that handles the package

Comment: Okay, but since I am setting the config, the environment is not ready yet, so wrapping it in a Meteor.startup() is relevant or not ? If you prefer could it lead to bugs setting config inside Meteor.startup() ?

Comment: the external packages load before your config.js. config.js will be loaded and executed before the Meteor.startup. so your environment should be ready. I dont think you should use Meteor.startup()  to config in the server